# How to do correlation just between columns in Python Seaborn?

Tags: python, seaborn, data-visualization, correlation

i have so many columns or variables, but actually I just want to know the correlation betweeen some columns because it is too much. may be I can divided the data by 5 times. I use the code like this

````
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))
cmap = sns.diverging_palette(222, 10, as_cmap=True)
_ = sns.heatmap(df_new.corr(), annot=True, vmax=.8, square=True, cmap=cmap)```
````

and the output is
[image: Heatmap Correlation]
isnt it to much?
How can I divided the data into several columns like 25 columns for  1 heatmap not 120 variables for 1 heatmap correlation?
Thank you for helping me!

Comment: what you're *actually* looking for seems to be *PCA*. But you forgot to ask a question that we can actually answer!

Comment: sorry I already edited the question

Answer (score 1):

create a new `df` that includes all the columns that you want to plot the correlations for and then include this df in the data attribute of the sns.heatmap() function.

Comment: Good Idea! @intedgar